# Is it possible to get color code from flash app?

Tags: flash, bots

I want to write bot for photo hunt game like this [one](http://www.liquidfuse.com), so I need to read every pixel and see if two pictures have difference color code. But don't have any experienced about flash before. Is it possible to write something like this and how ?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't know what a "photo hunt game" is. Need a little more details on exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible!

Comment: Could you give me some clues or resources ?